# Context for RDF Graph can not be set

Tags: ruby, rdf, sesame

I am trying to give a context to my triples:

```
repo = Sesame_Repository.new("http://localhost:8080/openrdf-sesame/repositories/CONTEXT")
graph = RDF::Graph.new

sub = RDF::URI("https://force.it/base")
pre = RDF::URI("https://force.it/has")
obj = RDF::Literal("ABC Weapons")
context = RDF::URI("https://force.it")

graph << [sub, pre, obj, context]
graph.each_statement do |statement|
repo.public_insert_statement(statement)
end
```

But the context ist not set. Is this not possible anymore? or how can I set the context to my graph?

( I can save triples but when I am adding context it wether saves the context nor the triples)

EDIT: When using repository instead of graph the context stays empty

```
graph = RDF::Repository.new << RDF::Statement.new(sub, pre, obj, :context => RDF::URI("https://force.it"))
```

Comment: What do you mean by a "context"?  Do you mean that you want to store the triples in a named graph?

Comment: Exactly, as you can see in the code I tried to put a triple with a name into the sesame repo, but the context (or named graph) is not saved.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor "context" is what the fourth item in a quad is called in Sesame. You use it to store named graphs, but the mechanism predates named graphs, hence the different name.

Comment: I don't know anything about Ruby, but setting context definitely is possible in Sesame - perhaps the version of the ruby connector you're using is not compatible with your version of Sesame?

Comment: Thanks to gkellog (developer of ruby rdf gem) :"

A graph is a simple container for triples. When it's creates, you can provide it with a single context. This is because a graph is really a projection of a named graph from a repository (dataset).

You can use RDF::Repository instead of RDF::Graph in this example, as a repository does support contexts. The RDF concept is of a Quad, where the last e,event is an optiona graph name (uri or BNode). The notion of context can me earlier in RDF.rb.
" The topic got much more clarified.

Comment: FWIW Sesame's API has the notion of a `Model`, which is a simple container for quads (so including the named graph). Not sure if the ruby rdf gem has an equivalent for that though. As mentioned by the developer of the gem though, working with the repository directly is of course a good solution.

Comment: In fact, you should post your comment as an answer to the question - that way it's clear to other people with a similar problem what the solution is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to gkellog (developer of ruby rdf gem) :" A graph is a simple container for triples. When it's creates, you can provide it with a single context. This is because a graph is really a projection of a named graph from a repository (dataset). You can use RDF::Repository instead of RDF::Graph in this example, as a repository does support contexts. The RDF concept is of a Quad, where the last e,event is an optiona graph name (uri or BNode). The notion of context can me earlier in RDF.rb. " The topic got much more clarified. –  [to the github-issue of ruby RDF](https://github.com/ruby-rdf/rdf/issues/164#issuecomment-57489043)

SOLUTION FOR Sesame:

```
# create repository from public Sesame_Repository (see lib/rdf/sesame_repo.rb)
repo = Sesame_Repository.new("http://localhost:8080/openrdf-sesame/repositories/CONTEXT")
#Save Context
repo.set_context(RDF::URI("https://force.it/"))

# --intialize graph for sesame --
#create triple  
sub = RDF::URI("https://force.it/base")
pre = RDF::URI("https://force.it/has")
obj = RDF::Literal("Machinegun")
 # save triple to the repo
graph = RDF::Repository.new << RDF::Statement.new(sub, pre, obj)
graph.each_statement do |statement|
   repo.public_insert_statement(statement)
    puts statement.inspect
end
```